# Logic and function from integers into integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Let $F: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ if $m>n$ then $F(n) >F(m)$, let $A_n = F^{-1} [\{0,1,\cdots,n-1\}]$, prove that for all $n$ we have that $A_n\subset \mathbb{N}^{< n}$ ?

My attempt : by induction ,

Base case : $A_0 = \emptyset \subset \mathbb{N}^{< 0} = \emptyset$

Assume that $A_n\subset \mathbb{N}^{< n}$, i want to prove that $A_{n+1} \subset \mathbb{N}^{< n+1}$ , otherwise there is $a \in A_{n+1}- \mathbb{N}^{< n+1}$ , meaning $a\geq n+1$ and $F(a)=n$

If $a>n+1$ then $F(a)= n >F(n+1)$ so $F(n+1) \in {0,1,\cdots,n-1}$ meaning $n+1 \in A_n$ contradicting the assumption, but i got stuck in the **case $a=n+1$**

Comment: How could there exist a _strictly_ decreasing function $F$ from natural numbers to natural numbers?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco it does not need to be onto for example $F(i)=i+1$ is such function

Comment: I guess there is a typo in your post, then. In the first line of your post you define $F$ as a _strictly decreasing_ function. In your comment, you give an example of a _strictly increasing_ function for $F$.

Comment: What does $\mathbb{N}^{< n}$ mean?

Comment: Also  $F$ is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, but $F^{-1}$ seems to be a function from (Finite) Powersets to Powersets. Is $F^{-1}$ an *induced* function? Can you please make the corrections and clarifications needed to the question?